# Using assign inside $test$plusargs in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

In my code, I want to do some connections using assign statement for all my tests except one test for which I added a runtime argument "HB_CONN_DISABLE" in my testlist. When I code as follows,I get the below error

```
  if (!$test$plusargs("HB_CONN_DISABLE"))  
  begin
  assign iol.hb_valid_in = dp_if_tx_inject.hb_bar_val_in;
  assign iol.hb_in = dp_if_tx_inject.heartbeat_in;
  end

 Error-[V2KGEUV] Unknown or bad value for genvar
 -I-:/nfs/hd/disks/mgr_0240/...............soc_post.sv, 543
 Instance/Generate block name: iolc_tb
-I-:  Elaboration time unknown or bad value encountered for generate if-statement 
-I-:  condition expression.
-I-:  Please make sure it is elaboration time constant.
```

I also tried something like below, but in this case it doesn't recognize hb_bar_param in this line  if(hb_bar_param==0) may be because by that time the parameter doesn't get the value

```
  initial begin
  if ($test$plusargs("HB_BAR_TI_CONN_DISABLE"))  
  begin
  parameter hb_bar_param=1;
  end
  else
  begin
  parameter hb_bar_param=0;
  end
  end

 if(hb_bar_param==0)
 begin
 assign statements......
 end
```

I also tried using assign with ternary operator like the following

```
 assign iol.hb_valid_in = ($test$plusargs("...somthing..")) ? (... some value ...) : (... some other value ...);
```

but in that case I will still end up assigning something if the testplus args is false, but for me the requirement is that I dont want to assign at all if the testplus args is there, please help me with this problem

Basically I want the following code for all my tests except one test for which I added testplus args.Is this illegal or is there any way to do it.

```
 assign iol.hb_valid_in = dp_if_tx_inject.hb_bar_val_in;
 assign iol.hb_in = dp_if_tx_inject.heartbeat_in;
```

Comment: Hi, I just added in the end of the question, just two assign statements., so basically you mean there is no way I can decide if the assignments happen based on a testplusarg ?

Answer (score -1):

A `parameter` is a compile time (elaboration time) construct which is defined before you run the program.

The `if` statements in your case which are the first-rank members in the module code are a `generate` construct which is also a compile-time thing.

Plusargs are passed to the already compiled model when you run it and `$test$plusargs` is a dynamic function executed at run time. Therefore it cannot be used to modify the generated part.

`assign` is a continuous assignment and is used to assign wires. Therefore, lhs always has to be assigned.  Therefore, you desire to not assign something is using this statement is not possible.

However in case you declare the `hb_valid_in` as `reg` or as `logic`, you can just create a latch statement as the following:

```
always @*
   if (!$test$plusargs("HB_CONN_DISABLE"))
      iol.hb_valid_in = some_value;
```

So, it will assign a 'some_value' to 'hb_valid_in' only if the condition is true. Otherwise it will not.

This is all under assumption that you create a non-synthesizable test bench module.